# How to check if a server member can send message in a particular channel in discord js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Suppose there is a server and I have a slash command by which a user can send an embed message. In that command, it have a option to choose in which channel you want to send that embed message and I want to ensure that if a user can send message in the channel they provided in slash command options then only they are able to use that slash command.

I hope someone know how  to do this.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a channel in `channel`, a guild in `guild`, and a user in `user`, you can get the perms like this:

```
const permissions = channel.permissionsFor(guild.members.cache.get(user.id));
```

If you already have the member (as `member`):

```
const permissions = channel.permissionsFor(member);
```

Then you can just check if they have the permissions:

```
if (permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages)) {
    // member has perms to send in the channel
}
```

See [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#permissions) page in the guide.